# Why does the request return more data than the inserted interface?

Tags: angular, interface, ngrx-effects

I'm making a request for an API where it contains several values, but I don't need them all.

For this I created the interfaces, to be able to type and use the correct objects.

However my object is getting "dirty" because in addition to the interface values, it is going to the other values ​​that I didn't want from the API.

What to do?

**Example:**

```
IApiData {
   example 1: {
      hello: string;
   }
   example 2: [{ hello2: string; }]
}
```

And then in the result of the request I get this:

```
IApiData {
   example 1: {
      hello: '1',
      hello2: '2'
   }
   example 2: [{
      hello2: '2',
      hello3: '3'
   }]
}
```

In summary, what I do is this:

Service request:

```
getLastFiveDays(cityLat: number, cityLng: number): Observable<IWeatherLastFiveDays> {
        return this.http.get<IWeatherLastFiveDays>(`${this.endpoint}/onecall/timemachine`, {
            headers: this.headers,
            params: {
                dt: this.dateUtils.getLastFiveDaysInSeconds().toString(),
                lat: cityLat.toString(),
                lon: cityLng.toString(),
            },
        });
    }
```

Store effect:

```
getAllConditions$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
        ofType(action.GET),
        switchMap(({ cityName, countryIsoCode, cityLat, cityLng }) =>
            forkJoin([this.backendService.getLastFiveDays(cityLat, cityLng), this.backendService.getNextFiveDays(cityName, countryIsoCode, cityLat, cityLng)]).pipe(
                map(results => {
                    const lastFiveDaysResult = results[0];
                    const nextFiveDaysResult = results[1];

                    return action.GET_SUCCESS({
                        weather: {
                            id: cityName,
                            nextFiveDays: nextFiveDaysResult,
                            currentDay: lastFiveDaysResult.current,
                            lastFiveDays: lastFiveDaysResult.hourly,
                        },
                    });
                }),
                catchError(error =>
                    of(
                        action.GET_FAIL({
                            error: {
                                status: error.cod,
                                message: error.message,
                            },
                        })
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your question there are two important points to mention.

First, an interface is a contract, and you should use in that way. In other words, it should not matter the "dirty" things, what it matter is that the object fulfill the contract.

Second, citing the web,

> TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript.

I would say that you should think of TypeScript as a really good tool to build software, and TypeScript lives till it compiles. In other words, on runtime there is not type checking, if it does not match you will get an error when tying to access something that does not exist or is not as expected.

Simple way of keeping the minimum object to fulfill interface contract,

```
interface ApiData {
   example1: {
      hello: string;
   }
   example2: [
      {
         hello2: string;
      }
   ]
}

function minObjForApiData (obj) {
   const example1 = { hello: obj.example1.hello };
   const example2 = obj.example2.map(v => { hello2: v.hello2});
   return {
      example1,
      example2
   };
}
```

Comment: I understand what I said, and I understand what an interface is, that's why I was curious.

If I created a contract, why is it "getting dirty" by adding extra properties to my object?

Should I do this "cleaning" of the request response myself?

How should I do it?

Comment: Like I mention, those are two different things .. You are seeing the "dirt" because you are inspecting, and you do not need to inspect, it doesn't matter, the relevant issue here is that the provider implements the contract .. Why are you so interested in not having the "dirty" staff?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't finish my last comment .. If you need to do a "cleaning", I think the easy way is to simply creating a minimum object that fulfill the contract, in the end is what you are looking for